# matplotlib bar chart with labels: space out the bars

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When I run this code in Jupyter notebook the labels overlap and are unreadable.

```
y = [72, 21, 114, 52, 114, 12, 101, 16, 68, 118]
x = np.arange(len(y))
columns = ['MAHC_A', 'MAHC_B', 'MAHC_C', 'MAHC_D', 'MAHC_E', 'MAHC_F','MAHC_G', 'MAHC_H', 'MAHC_I', 'MAHC_J']
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x, y, width=bar_width)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(xlabels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there a way to space these out?

Comment: Make your figure wider using the `figsize=[width, height]` kwarg to `subplots`?

Comment: The title and the question are a bit contradictory. Do you want to add space between the bars or between the labels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Make the figure larger in the horizontal direction.

   ```
   fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,4))
   ```
2. Make the fontsize smaller

   ```
   ax.set_xticklabels(columns, fontsize=8)
   ```
3. Rotate the labels, such that they won't overlap anymore.

   ```
   ax.set_xticklabels(columns, rotation=45)
   ```

Or, of course any combination of those.